# Is the same to use || instead OR and && instead of AND in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, comparison-operators

My question is the one stated in the title:
"Is the same to use || instead OR and && instead of AND in MYSQL?"

I know that normally you use "AND" or "OR" as comparison operators in SQL but it (seems that) work also "&&" and "||" (like in Java/Javascript etc.) in MYSQL. Is that correct?

Thank you for the aclaration

Comment: It is. But it's absolutely not standard compliant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, they are indeed equivalent—with the following exceptions as documented under [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/operator-precedence.html):

> The meaning of some operators depends on the SQL mode:
>
> - By default, [`||`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) is a logical [`OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) operator. With [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) enabled, [`||`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) is string concatenation, with a precedence between [`^`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor) and the unary operators.
> - By default, [`!`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not) has a higher precedence than `NOT`. With [`HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_high_not_precedence) enabled, [`!`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not) and `NOT` have the same precedence.
>
> See [Section 5.1.7, “Server SQL Modes”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

The manual is quite thorough :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html it is the same!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html), yes, it is the same.